# sharepoint workflow copy document from one subsite to another subsite document library in office 365

Tags: workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create **Designer Workflow** to copy document from one **subsite A** document library  to another **subsite B**  document Library. I've tried but unable to done task using SharePoint Designer,

is that possible using **ootb workflow action**?

If not possible then suggest some approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. SharePoint designer actions are limited in scope to the current site's artifacts. In Codeplex you have the SPDActivities that among others enables you to copy or move items and files across sites.

http://www.codeplex.com/SPDActivities

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1d4031d9-4f4b-4571-b67d-7fc5d976496b/how-to-copy-an-item-from-one-list-to-another-subsite-list?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

Comment: Can i use it in Office 365 site?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, SPD doesn't allow you to do this. As a solution, you can use 3rd party components.

I would recommend you to use [Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/)  it contains [Copy Document from Library](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/documents-list-items-processing/#CopyFile) workflow action which can do it.

I'm one of the developers of the product, so I'm glad to recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Share point Designer list custom workflow .

Open Designer -> Open Site in it -> Select List you want document copy ->select Action (Copy list item )-> Configured It -> Published Workflow.

--> Set workflow Settings.

Referred Link :
[Copy document from one library to other](https://cypher19.wordpress.com/workflow-copy-document-from-one-library-to-another/)

Happy Coding:)

dipshare1

Comment: Will it work for one subsite library to another subsite library ?

Comment: Wait, ill get back to you with confirmation

Comment: @Dipen i am not able to select Destination document libarray , because it is in another subsite

Comment: @I-touch  I am not sure, as per my knowledge , sharepoint designer is not  providing  site to site document copy functionality. We can manage by pro grammatically. or other option in using console application move stp file to other site