# Copy Document From on subsite to another subsite + REST API + SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow(On Premise)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, designer-workflow, ootb, copy

I have 2 different sites under same site collection on SharePoint 2013(on Premise).

Initially file will be uploaded in one site. After the file approval, I wanted to Copy that file to another site(sibling site) under same site collection.

I want these documents on both sites as both sites will have different permissions.

Let me know if this is possible using any OOTB features or SharePoint 2013 designer workflow?

If it is possible then how can I achieve this? Anyone else come across such requirement ever?

Comment: Possible Solution to your problem: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166793/sharepoint-workflow-copy-document-from-one-subsite-to-another-subsite-document-l

Comment: Have you looked at the content organizer? It sounds like a good case for that

Comment: I don't wanna use third party tools. I was looking for OOTB way using default SharePoint features only.

Comment: Content organizer moves the document to single destination only. I want this document in both sub sites.

Comment: If you really want to duplicate content (which I normally don't recommend) it might be vise to ensure that both do not show up in search. I guess that the appoved version should be read only so perhaps it would be a good idea to convert to PDF and move that file?

Comment: This is a good starting point on using web service calls in a SPD workflow:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-web-services-in-sharepoint-workflows-using-sharepoint-designer

Comment: Anyone else come across such requirement ever??